# SQL Query for finding number of days in a month of year 2022

Tags: sql, sql-server

Need this table as output

[image: 1]

```
DECLARE @ADate DATETIME
SET @ADate = GETDATE()
SELECT DAY(EOMONTH(@ADate)) AS DaysInMonth
```

Output: Jan 31 (I got only one month’s output. I need all the months in 2022 and their days)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I've gone ahead and removed the tag spam here; please only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using. Tagging multiple conflicting technologies makes your question unclear and thus *harder* to answer. It is also unlikely to get your question "more views" and likely to have the opposite effect, where only users who know *all* the RDBMS you have (mis)tagged will entertain the question; that is often a very small portion of the user base. Tag spam is far more likely to result in your question receiving downvotes and/or being closed as unclear. Please [edit] your question to retag the correct RDBMS.

Comment: Sounds like you need to invest in a calendar table

Comment: See [/editing-help#tables](/editing-help#tables) for how to make markup tables.

Comment: I don't understand the question - do you need days by month from a given date to 31/12/22? if so you shouldn't be using getdate which will be todays date ie 2023

Comment: Yes. Number of days in a month for year 2022. (from 1/1/22 to 31/12/22)

Comment: Which **database** do you use? Answer depends on that.

Comment: Are you merely looking for something like `select day(eomonth('2022-01-01')) union all select day(eomonth('2022-02-01')) union all ...`?

Comment: Let me try this one Thorsten :)

Comment: @Littlefoot The columns go as : Day(1,2,3…)|Day of Week(Mon,Tues,Wed…)|MonthName(Jan,Jan,Jan…)|Date(2022-01-01,2022-01-02,2022-01-03)….|

Comment: When I asked about the database, I had Microsoft SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL, MySQL and similar on mind. Syntax is different and so is solution. I guess that some kind of a *row generator* should be used but - again - **which database do you use**?

Comment: @Littlefoot Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
 WITH  months AS
        (
        SELECT  1 AS MONTH
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  MONTH + 1
        FROM    months
        WHERE   MONTH < 12
        )
SELECT CAST(DATENAME(month, CONCAT("2022-" , months.MONTH, "-01")) AS CHAR(3)) AS 'MONTH' , DAY(EOMONTH(CONCAT("2022-" , months.MONTH, "-01"))) as DAY  FROM months
```

Output:

| MONTH | DAY |
| --- | --- |
| Jan | 31 |
| Feb | 28 |
| Mar | 31 |
| Apr | 30 |
| May | 31 |
| Jun | 30 |
| Jul | 31 |
| Aug | 31 |
| Sep | 30 |
| Oct | 31 |
| Nov | 30 |
| Dec | 31 |

Create a row generator from 1 to 12 using [WITH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) ,after that is just formating the output

You can view the result here: https://onecompiler.com/sqlserver/3yurzpsnm